# Prevent the ::after selector being part of the link?

Tags: html, css

Googled myself stupid, still couldn't seem to find any information on it. Following issue:

Adding an ::after selector to a link adds it as part of the link. Is there a way that the ::after selector will not extend the link (be text only, not clickable)? See example, is there a way, that the "»" will not be part of the link?

Example:

```css
a::after {
  content: " »";
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Test</a>
```

Comment: No, that is not possible in a trivial way. Pseudo elements render as if they were _children_ of the element you apply them to.

Comment: Maybe this can help you : stackoverflow.com/questions/10077386/how-to-display-the-after-content-outside-element

Comment: @Fifi will have a look, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make its width 0 and add `pointer-events: none;`

```css
a::after {
  content: " »";
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:8px;
  width:0;    
  pointer-events: none;
}

a {
  font-size:35px;
  margin-right:20px; /* to avoid overflow issue and cover the area of the pseudo element */
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Test</a> some text after
```

Comment: Ah, `width:0` is clever, I tried only `pointer-events: none`, and as expected, that alone did not work.

Comment: @CBroe yes it's needed to prevent the contribution of the pseudo element to the width of the link and get trapped by its events

Comment: Very clever solution indeed! How is it with compatability tho – as far as I'm aware pointer events are terrible for IE up to IE10?

Comment: @k1p57a IE is dead, I don't think it really matter if it's supported in IE10 and lower (at least for me)

Comment: @TemaniAfif fair enough. Will go with that solution. Thanks again!